# Repositioning a <video> element with media queries

Tags: media-queries

I've got this page at [stevedillon.net](http://stevedillon.net/WNM/13/13_Dillon.html) and the  element is centered on a 1280x1024 viewport, but is off center at other sizes. At 1280x1024, the CSS #video has pushed the element to the center using margin-left: 13%;.

I'd like to fix it so it's centered in different viewport sizes using media queries. I've tried the following, but no luck. Any thoughts? Thanks

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
    #video{
        width: 1200px;
        margin-left: 33%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the following media queries. Adding the viewport range helped control the size of the video container as did adding the `width` property above `1680px`.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1670px) and (min-width: 1280px) and 
(orientation: landscape) #video {
    margin-left: 20%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1900px) and (min-width: 1680px) and 
(orientation: landscape) #video {
  margin-left: 13%;
  width: 1200px !important;
}
```